# What is the purpose of program files directory in windows?

Tags: windows, installation

I wonder about this because we are developing an application, after installation some files were copied to program files and some to user profile directory.  But, we found some issues w.r.t program files.  Now all files are installed in the current user's directory.  Even Google Chrome, does so.  What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

If you install a given application on 10 different accounts, do you really want the application to exist 10 times on disk?

Answer (score 2):

The program files directory is for just that, the executable files, dlls, assemblies and other executable code and non editable configuration data associated with a program. The user profile directory is for data and code associated with the individual user.

Answer (score 2):

The **program files** directory in Windows is a place where all the installed files go.
But there are some customizations needed depending on users. Those go into user's directory.
Like Downloads folder, customization of Mozilla firefox, Winamp, etc.

There has to be different profiles for each user to customize the applications.
But the commonly needed files of a software need not be installed in each user account; hence they are installed in **Program Files**

Answer (score 0):

Since Vista the Program Files directory has been marked as off limits so applications can't write to it by default unless given admin privileges.

This is for better security to stop other applications manipulating existing installed applications.

There is a good write up of this here on how to work with UAC but also learning to write more secure applications.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/magazine/cc163486.aspx

Comment: This has nothing to do with applications being installed in a given location, though, outside of allowing non-admin users to install it or update (which is a clear security issue anyway, when dealing with shared code).  There's no reason you can't install globally and store per-user data locally.